# UITextField to variable Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, variables, swift2

With Swift 2.0 a few things changed, for example this line doesn't work anymore:
`let weite=NSString(string:weiteTF.text!).doubleValue` it ends up in this: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

later in the code, I want to do some calculations with the variable *weite*, so it has to be formatted for numbers in this style "5.69"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No need to convert to an NSString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weiteTF.text seems to be an optional value which mean it can be nil. The error just show the value of it is nil but you were trying to hard unwrap it with "!" modifier. The best practice in swift 2.0 should be:

```
guard let text = weiteTF.text else{
     //or doing something else here
     return
}
let weite = NSString(string:text)
//...
```

If the rest of the code is never called, please make sure the instants of the textfield is the one you really want to work on. Have you linked the outlet if you're using IB? Did you pass the right selector with right format if you're using target-selector...